# Why CCLabelAtlas[1] refuses to update?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 7 CCLabelAtlas labels declared in .h file like this `CCLabelAtlas *numberStat[7]`. Then I then initialized them in a for loop in .m file:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=7; i++) {
    NSString* statName = [NSString stringWithFormat @"Number %d", i];
    numberStat[i] = [[CCLabelAtlas labelWithString: [self loadThisValue:statName] charMapFile:@"digitalNumbers.png" itemWidth:26 itemHeight:37 startCharMap:'0'] retain];
    [self addChild: numberStat[i]];
}
```

The problem comes when I try to update the label. I can update from 2 to 7 just fine, but when I try to update numberStat[1]'s string (`numberStat[1].string = @"111";`), it crashes. The exact same code works for 2-7.

Here's the crash log:

```
 -[CCSprite setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897cbd0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897cbd0'
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that somewhere in your code, numberStat[1] is being over-released, and by the time you come to assign a string to it, a CCSprite has moved into the memory that it occupied.

Comment: How I could make sure it won't get over-released? I already declared it with `retain`.